# Unavailable payment method for credit card on Paypal Sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

While testing Express Checkout on Sandbox, buyer is unable to find Payment Method for Credit Card.

Somewhere on the page we find following message.

> We're sorry, some of your payment methods are unavailable for this
>   purchase.
>
> Unavailable payment methods:
>
> Credit card, debit card, or instant bank transfer

The Seller account is [enabled](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_create-accounts/#accepting-credit-cards-in-test-transactions) as Business Pro.

Are we missing any configuration for Buyer or Seller account?

Answer (score 0):

This is generally a verification issue in the live environment. Check to see that the bank account attached is confirmed, and also that the email address is confirmed.